# Ubuntu Server - installation location when building from source

Tags: installation, ubuntu, make

I am pretty new to Ubuntu Server. I have installed libevent 1.4.13 from source but I am not exactly sure where the install location is after I do make install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where ever the default location is for that source package...

Your best bet is to install the package from Ubuntu.

apt-get update
apt-get install libevent-1.4-2 
(Not sure exactly what libevent you need, but there are a few listed in [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com))